# add and remove an element to a mathematical set

Tags: python

I'd like to write pseudo code with mathematical notation, I will write the code phrases in Python. I need to know if

**first question:**

```
aList = []
aList.empty() is not True
```

equals

$aList \neq \emptyset $

**second question**

```
a = 5
aList.append(a)
```

equals

$a \gets 5$

$aList \cup a$

**third question**

how to write to get the first element and remove it from the list i.e.:

```
curElement = aList[0]
aList.remove(0)
```

Thanks for any advice the Internet couldn't help me out.

Kind Regards

Comment: I don't understand your first question and your second.

Comment: Pardon me. 1) A list is often referred as a vector or a dynamic array i.e.: a container for multiple values. 2) I updated the question, the goal is to insert/append a new value to this list/array - I know $\cup$ usually stand for uniting two sets, however I'm not sure if that counts for a set and a sole value to as shown in the question

Comment: I see. For second question, it should be $aList \cup \{a\}$. For the third one, it should be $aList - \{curlElement\}$.

Comment: I guess $aList -\{ curElement \}$ stands for removing the element from the list, but how do I define which element from the set was chosen to assigne $curElement$ beforehand (i.e. how to retrieve an element from an arbitrary position in the set)?

Comment: We don't have "list" in math. We only have set.

Comment: I understand. That came unexpected though

Comment: @Misakov: We have tuples and functions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that mathematicians and computer scientists of that field (type system and so on) do have their own shorter notation for these operations. However, they are not that common among the general public.

**What are lists?**

There are many list like constructs in math. For mathematician they are all functions. Basically, a list/tuple is a function $f$ from $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ into a set, say $X$. So typically you define the set of lists with values in $X$ as its Kleene star:
$$ X^* = \{ f:\{1,\dotsc, n\} \to X \mid n \in\mathbb N \} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} X^n, $$
where $\mathbb N$ includes $0$.

Most computer scientists and mathematicians in that field use to work with partial functions. So you could also write
$$ X^* = \{ f:\mathbb N\to X \mid \operatorname{dom} f = \{1, \dotsc, |\operatorname{dom} f| \} \}. $$
They also identify $f$ with its graph, that is
$$ f = \{ (i,f(i)) \mid i\in\operatorname{dom} f \}. $$

**Answer to your question:**

Using partial functions you can express

1. "$f\in X^*$ is a empty list" by $f = \emptyset$,
2. "$g\in X^*$ is $f\in X^*$ appended with $a\in X$" by
   $$ g = f \cup \{ (|\operatorname{dom} f| + 1, a) \}, $$
3. "$g\in X^*$ is $f\in X^*$ removed the first element" by
   $$ g = \{ (i-1, f(i)) \mid i\in \operatorname{dom} f\setminus\{1\} \}. $$

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, it brought some light in here. However I guess it looks more complicated as it would make sense in this case. Since the goal of this pseudo code structure is to facilitate the understanding of rather complex text phrase - at this point of the paper for people barely dealing with mathematical expressions.

Comment: @user3085931: Concerning pseudo code, some common concepts can be explained in text more easily :) There is no need to use formula with uncommon notations or concepts.

Comment: Not when considering that programmers tend to be lazy guys, skipping text and rather used to read code ;) I'm thinking about a way inbetween atm